# Get the column that is used to sort the table / get primary sorter

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-plugins, datatables

I have a datatable that is created server side. This table includes start and end dates, along with some other data.

I would like to add rows that state the total duration spent. For example, if the table is sorted based on the procedures column, I would like to add a row after each group of procedures.

I know how to add rows client side, what I don't know is how do I check which column is the primary sorter?

I found an example that creates a new row based on the first column. I need something similar, only based on the primary sorter.

```
 var sGroup = oSettings.aoData[ oSettings.aiDisplay[iDisplayIndex] ]._aData[0];
```

Comment: What do you mean by-`which column is the primary sorter?`

Comment: mmh, the column that is used to sort the table. As far as I know, datatables can support multiple sorters, which is a functionality I plan to use. For now though I'm happy with just using one column to sort the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the array of arrays you passed when constructing the table by accessing this property of your table object:

```
oTable.dataTableSettings[0].aaSorting
//in my case returns [[1, "desc", 1]]
```

Actually i don't know what the third parameter is but i think you can experiment a little and find the answer!

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. Right now I'm back to working on other things :)